# Facebook like button not rendering in div with display:none

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I am well aware that there are almost 10 duplicates of this question. But solutions of none of them work for me. So here are the details:

I am using `carousel` from bootstrap. I use `carousel` to display set of 3 divs on each cycle.
The structure is as follows:

```
   <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="active item">
            <div class="span4>content along with FB like button </div>
            <div class="span4>content along with FB like button </div>
            <div class="span4>content along with FB like button </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item"> <!-- this div has display:none -->
         <div class="span4>content along with FB like button </div>
         <div class="span4>content along with FB like button </div>
         <div class="span4>content along with FB like button </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
    <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
    </div>
```

Above is the stripped down version, just to leave out the unnecessary stuff. The problem is, all the Facebook like buttons inside the `div` which has `display:none` set have `width` and `height` set to `0`.

This problem occurs in Firefox(the latest version).

I am using the HTML5 version of like button generated using [FB like button configurator](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/).

Below is the resultant like button code in the hidden div:

```
<div data-show-faces="true" data-width="450" layout="box_count" data-send="false" class="fb-like fb_edge_widget_with_comment fb_iframe_widget" fb-xfbml-state="rendered">
    <span style="height: 0px; width: 0px;">

        <iframe scrolling="no" style=" height: 0px; width: 0px; class="fb_ltr fb_iframe_widget_lift" src="">
        </iframe>

    </span>
</div>
```

The like buttons in the active divs are the only ones visible. Even those in the modals (which are hidden initially) are not visible too.
How do I make it visible when div has display:none?

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same issue you are having and my code solution is below.  The key thing to note is that anytime you see the facebook generated code having a height and width of 0 it means that the facebook button is loaded while the CSS on it is display:none.  You can't just force it to be displayed because it is possible that the facebook button hasn't fully loaded by the time the bootstrap carousel has loaded.  The trick is to display all your items in the carousel using `active` on the initial load then once your facebook buttons have loaded you can remove `active` from your non-starting slide.

```
   <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
<div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="active item">
        <div class="span4>content along with FB like button </div>
        <div class="span4>content along with FB like button </div>
        <div class="span4>content along with FB like button </div>
    </div>

    <div class="active item"> <!-- this div also is active for initial load -->
     <div class="span4>content along with FB like button </div>
     <div class="span4>content along with FB like button </div>
     <div class="span4>content along with FB like button </div>
    </div>
</div>

<a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
<a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
</div>



window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
    FB.Event.subscribe('xfbml.render', function () {
$('.carousel-inner>.item:not(:first-child)').removeClass('active');
    });}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you set a `div` to `display:none;` by default all of the child objects will have `display:none` which means they wont show up. Same if you set the size to zero.

IMHO it's not the right way to do it, but try setting the child object to `display: block;` or `display: inline;` and giving it a defined size.

Answer (score 1):

Put iframe version of Like button in any hidden content and it will work.

worked for me like a charm

Comment: Could you elaborate on this a bit? And/or add some example code?

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue but only in IE. I saw that iframe width and height stayed 0. This solved my problem:

```
.fb-like.fb_iframe_widget iframe{
  width:60px !important;
  height:60px !important;                                
}
```